# VBA - call function on next cell when specified range is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of empty cell eg: A1 to A5

I would like to have a private sub to call an function on B1 to B5 whenever A1 to A5 cell is filled up.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are going to use **Worksheet Change Event** + **IsEmpty** method to help you determine "whenever A1 to A5 cell is filled up". For programming with worksheet event, you should place your code in the corresponding worksheet object, not normal module object. Below the code shall get u start

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Me.Range("A1:A5")
            If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next cell

        'Call YourOwnFunction(......) From Here...
    End If

End Sub
```

if you want **any** of the cell is filled up instead of the all cells filled up:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Me.Range("A1:A5")
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                'Call YourOwnFunction(......) From Here...
                 Exit Sub
            End If
        Next cell      
    End If      
End Sub
```

Comment: i tested the code but it seems only all range A1:A5 filled up only will trigger the fuction.. i need whenever any cell in A1 to A5 is filled up it willl trigger the fuction..

Comment: @JiakeeLee, I thought you mean all the cell is filled up. I modified the solution

Answer (score 0):

In worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.CountA([A1:A5]) = 5 Then
        '// Your code here
    End If
End Sub
```